# Convergence of an infinite series containing the sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Does the following infinite series converge?

$\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (k)}{\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}}$

In case it converges, does it have a closed-form value or solution? Or just a numerical solution?

Comment: The series converges because you can replace $\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}$ with $\sqrt[3]{k^2}$ and since $\sin(k)$ has a bounded antiderivative and $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}}$ is monotonically decreasing to zero you can use Dirichlet theorem to deduce that the series converges. I don't know about a closed form.

Comment: @Yanko. There is a closed form if we remove the $+1$.

Answer (score 3):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) can be used to show the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(n)a_n$$

for any monotone $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ that tends to $0$.

It is doubtful that this has a closed form, though numerical approximation can be managed. For example, [this program](https://tio.run/##TY6xDoMwDET3fIWXStCIkDAi@IAOlbqjDFBADRWhCmFof546BtR68UV3vhe3NO91nZcRSpCsdg53pZnv3DijzCQOY/3kwIKxoITYrHZigBMOeQnX2j/EbGxk45T0vXE@smfLVUy5UFwUFDc9xfP8doEEW0@/ZwGKdbbdeMPOE3iL3Z/uYAbzGUz5ZybDYe@46qnx/9GmOC2udJxmFAoUIr2csZ7yUq/rFw) gives the approximation:

$$0.8529108\approx\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}$$

and [this program](https://tio.run/##LYwxEsMgDAR7XqFSgtiYpMuMH@PCiSkQGkEKXo8dkqtu5m5XWj0y3ydp0npMkrVC2urRyyfBCoupu6ZytbD8Y15ZgSEy6MbvHcMNxoeeBr6QW4dgLpGRyeIYXZiYPLJlF8haDLN/kBGNXPGC/M/Q@wk) gives:

$$0.852910820165\approx\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

As Yanko commented
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (k)}{\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}} <\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (k)}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}}= \frac{1}{2} i
   \left(\text{Li}_{\frac{2}{3}}\left(e^{-i}\right)-\text{Li}_{\frac{2}{3}}\left(e^
   i\right)\right)\approx 1.06095$$